LLM prompt chain does not behave as expected
I'm trying to rephrase wording of an original text, and translate that into desirable language.
For that purpose, I decided to use chains on LangChain.
Although, the output is always rephrased, it is never translated.
The key code snippets are as below.
# Define the ChatPromptTemplate
prompt = ChatPromptTemplate.from_messages(
    [
        ("system", file_content),
        ("system", "The reprahsed car audit report should be in the following language: {language}."),
        ("user", "\n{input}"),
    ]
)

# Set up the output parser
output_parser = StrOutputParser()

# Create the chain
chain = prompt | llm | output_parser

...

# Language selection with different labels and values
language_options = {
    "cs": "Czech (CZ)",
    "sk": "Slovak (SK)",
    "en": "English (EN)",
    "de": "German (DE)",
    "it": "Italian (IT)",
    "pl": "Polish (PL)",
    "ro": "Romanian (RO)",
    "sq": "Albanian (SQ)"
}
labels = list(language_options.keys())
selected_label = st.radio("Vyberte cílový jazyk výstupu:", labels, horizontal=True, index=labels.index("cs"))
selected_language = language_options[selected_label]  # Get the corresponding value from the dictionary

st.markdown("---")
if st.button('Upravit text'):
    with st.spinner('Prosím počkejte, odpověď se generuje...'):
        # Invoke the chain with user input and selected language code
        answer = chain.invoke({"input": user_input, "language": selected_language})
        st.text_area("Odpověď", value=answer, height=500, key='answer')

Advise would be appreciated.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

You haven't provided any instructions to the model. You should update the chat_prompt as follows:
system_message = "You are a helpful assistant specializing in rephrasing and translating text."

human_template = prompt = "Your task comprises two steps:\n\n1. Rephrase the provided text: {input}.\
        \n2. Translate the rephrased sentence into: {language}."


chat_prompt = ChatPromptTemplate.from_messages(
    [
        ("system", system_message),
        ("human", human_template),
    ]
)

The problem comes from the confusion of the 3 different types of messages we use in ChatPromptTemplate:

System Message: These messages include guidance and clarifications for the bot on how to behave.
Human Message: This is the input from the user, where we write the instructions/actions we want the model to perform.
AI Message: Responses generated by the AI model.

ChatPromptTemplate Documentation
